# Can I create overlapping bar charts using Google Chart Tools?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm using [Google Chart Tools](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/) to create charts for some of my data. I'm pretty much confined to the examples I can find in the [Charts Gallery](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery), and I can't find an example of an overlapping bar chart like this (mspaint):

[image: Chart example]

Is it possible to create a chart like this with Google Chart Tools?

Answer (score 2):

This is called "stacked bar chart" in Google Chart Tools. To create one you simply make a [BarChart](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart) with multiple values per row and set the `isStacked` option to `true`. Example result:

[image: Chart]